# How do I regularly post excel data to a web service?

Tags: excel, vsto, excel-dna

I have a user requirement that I have been battling with for a while with no success. I need to write an add-in that can read around 100 formula-driven cells (of a specific spreadsheet) once every couple of minutes, and send to a web service.

I'm more than happy to use Excel-DNA or VSTO, but everything I've tried so far causes the user interface to hang for an instant. Would this always be the case if the data is being read from the active spreadsheet (even from a different thread) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading the sheet from a different thread is likely to have a worse effect than reading from the Excel main thread (say in an event or something). This is due to the COM threading switch that is required for the cross-thread calls. In the end, all the COM calls have to do their work on the main thread anyway.

You might have more success by hooking some of the Excel events, as a start the `Workbook.SheetChange` event, then checking whether the changes affect your watched Range(s) and updating an internal data structure with the new data.

You can then update the back-end periodically (or only when watched cells have change) from a background thread.

Comment: Govert, the data can be read on the main thread and other stuff (not related to the Excel object model) can be run on the secondary thread. Nobody said about touching Excel from a secondary thread. It is only your imagination.

Comment: @Eugene - I agree with you. My answer was to the original question, not in comment to your answer. In the last part of the question, James asked: "Would this always be the case if the data is being read from the active spreadsheet (even from a different thread) ?"

Comment: Thank you both for responding, my testing did imply that the main sheet was affected but wasn't sure if I had implemented the DNA solution incorrectly. I will move further on with the SheetChange event and see if I have more joy there. Surprised how little information there is on using Excel as a data entry mechanism considering its widespread use in the Financial Markets sector.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run a secondary thread to post the data to the web service to prevent any UI freeze.